# Unexpected binding error with generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write method that accepts list of any elements that implement (my) HasId interface and returns element with given Id. But for some reason I got "Unexpected binding" compile error.

```
public abstract class HasIdUtil<T> extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

protected T findById(List<T extends HasId> hasIdList, String id) {
    for (T item : hasIdList) {
        if (id.equals(item.resolveId())) {
            return item;
        }
    }

    throw new ElementNotFoundException("There are no elements with id = " + id + " in given list");
}
}
```

And here is my interface:

```
public interface HasId<T> {
     T resolveId();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting unexpected binding error? or is it something else? If so can you tell me what line number you're getting it? Somehow I get the feeling that List<T extends HasId) is not valid.

Comment: Intellij Idea paints in red resolveId method for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I should have specified HasId< TYPE > and made generic key K as well.
Code below work as I want.

```
public abstract class HasIdUtil<V extends HasId<K>, K> extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

protected V findById(List<? extends V> hasIdList, K id) {
    for (V hasId : hasIdList) {
        if (id.equals(hasId.resolveId())) {
            return hasId;
        }
    }

    throw new ElementNotFoundException("There are no elements with id = " + id + " in given list");
}

}
```